# Is there going to be a 3rd season of V?

Tags: v

The second season of the TV series *V* ends dramatically. Is there a third season planned to come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On May 13, 2011, ABC announced that V was canceled**

^ Ausiello, Michael (May 13, 2011). "[Breaking: ABC Cancels Brothers & Sisters, V, Mr. Sunshine, Four Others](http://www.tvline.com/2011/05/breaking-abc-cancels-brothers-sisters-and-v/)". TV Line. Retrieved May 13, 2011.